# Changing the "Facebook App-Invite" dialog language

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-invite-friends

I am using App Invites in my app to let users invite their friends to use the app, but today I noticed a problem.
The app invite dialog is in a foreign language (with cyrillic letters in my case, as in the photo below).

[image]

Is there a way to change it, to reflect the user's device language, or to set it permanently to English ?

**Edit.**
The code I'm using to invite friends :

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
            AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                    .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                    .setPreviewImageUrl(photoUrl)
                    .build();
            AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are the device language settings, and what are the Facebook app's language settings on the test device?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snipped showing how you open the dialog.

Comment: Looks like this is a [known issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1146255612068692/)

Comment: Thanks @derabbink, I'll keep an eye on that thread, hopefully the Facebook team will come up with a fix or workaround soon.

Comment: Same issue i am facing. its showing me dialog in local language...